# Program Executing Differently From CMD

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a C# app that, when opened, reads a text file and outputs the lines into the list view. I have set this to run at startup with a reg key which does open it but the app just shows an empty list view. Same thing happens when I run it from cmd but everything works fine when I just double click on the file in explorer, there are no parameters/arguments to the app so this has really confused me, any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Does the application expect parameters or arguments?

Comment: Does you program use current directory property?

Comment: @rlemon Nope, there are no command line arguments expected

Comment: How did you set it to run?  Is it stuck in the start menu Startup folder?  Or did you have it run from the registry?  Or what - we have no idea?

Comment: @phillip I set it to run from the reg key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without looking at the code that reads the file. I suspect the current dir is the problem. Make sure to specificity full path to your text file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, I am currently just using the name as though it is working in the same directory as the exe for the program, I will give the full path a shot.

Comment: I like using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory when I need to know where the application is running from.